# Figuring out what cell in a slanted grid a point is in

Tags: math, grid

I have the following (simplified) situation in my game:

A slanted (sheared?) grid and a point somewhere in that grid. I have to figure out in which cell that point lies. Sorry if this is a noob question but I would really appreciate some help.

[image: Here's an image to illustrate]

We can see, visually, that the red point lies in (1,1) but how do I figure that out via code?

Of course if this was a standard grid, I would just do (x/100, y/250)

Answer (score 0):

You can define two base vectors - in this case horizontal vector `A=(100, 0)` and left-down vector like `B=(-20, 150)` are good. Base point `(0,0)`.

Now for point `P` express it's coordinates in components of vectors `A, B`:

```
u * ax + v * bx = px
u * ay + v * by = py
```

Solve this equation system for unknowns coefficients `u, v`. Integer parts of result coefficients correspond to cell row and column.

For given example `u,v` values should be about 2.2 and 1.8, so 1st row (counting from 0) and 2nd column